# Create a multiple WebAssembly projects in a single solution

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, hosted-blazor-webassembly

Please, see this question for [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71085690/set-base-href-on-publish-in-blazor-webassembly-project/71086484?noredirect=1#comment125690451_71086484)  and the answer by MrC aka Shaun Curtis

This question is about something I've tried to solve in the past without great success. Are you familiar with this [sample](http://github.com/javiercn/BlazorMultipleApps)  I've once downloaded and run it. It did not work. I then realized that I must add the base url to the url in the browser's address bar in order to run the first project, for instance: `https://localhost: 44302/FirstApp` That is, the Client project. And for the SecondClient it should be `https://localhost: 44302/SecondApp`. This is exactly how the sample app by [MrC aka Shaun Curtis](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Hydra) works, though he added a Razor Pages app to provide a menu for redirection to the four projects.

What I tried to do without much success is to make the first WebAssemby front end project, which is hosted, to be the default; that is when I run the app, or type in the address bar `https://localhost: 44302.` And if I type `https://localhost: 44302/FirstApp` I see the first stand alone WebAssembly project I added to the solution. And a second project, and a third project, and so on, all are WebAssembly projects. I could not do that: When I ran the default project everything is fine... I can navigate within the bounds of the project, route to the Counter page, FetchData page, etc.

But when I add the segment /FirstApp to the url in the address bar and hit enter, the Router displays the message "Sorry, there's nothing at this address." instead of navigating to the project represented by the base url /FirstApp/

Does anyone here have any idea how to achieve the requested feature I am looking for ?

Comment: As you've quoted my answer and sample App, I'll look into this for you.  Will be tomorrow as it's running late in the UK now  ;-)

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Medusa - and the demo site on Azure - https://blazr-medusa.azurewebsites.net/.  There's a hosted WASM as default and then three further WASM sites at `Grey`, `Green` and `Purple`.  There's a navigation button set in the top tool bar to navigate between SPAs.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, thanks...It works perfectly well. Please, answer the question so that I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  The recent spate of questions on here has prompted me to update my article and original Repo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a summary of the Repo that demonstrates how to do this.

The sub-folder Web Assembly projects have project files like this.  The important bit is setting the `<StaticWebAssetBasePath>`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <StaticWebAssetBasePath>grey</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
    </PropertyGroup>
....
```

and `Index.html` like this.  We've updated the paths on the `base`, css and the framework js file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Blazr.Medusa.Grey</title>
    <base href="/grey/" />
    <link href="/grey/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/grey/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Blazr.Medusa.Grey.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="/grey/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The Web Project has dependencies on all the Web Assembly projects, so they can all be mapped to `wwwwroot`.

The Web Project `Program` looks like this with specific end points for each Web Assembly SPA.  The default maps to the base Web Assembly project - *Blazr.Medusa.WASM*.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/grey"), app1 =>
{
    app1.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/grey");
    app1.UseRouting();
    app1.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/grey/{*path:nonfile}", "/grey/index.html");
    });
});

app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/green"), app1 =>
{
    app1.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/green");
    app1.UseRouting();
    app1.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/green/{*path:nonfile}", "/green/index.html");
    });
});

app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/purple"), app1 =>
{
    app1.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/purple");
    app1.UseRouting();
    app1.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/purple/{*path:nonfile}", "/purple/index.html");
    });
});

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("");

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();


app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

app.Run();
```

The Site Links component in the `MainLayout` of each site provides navigation between the SPA's

```
<div class="p-2 m-2 text-end">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary me-1" @onclick='() => Go("")'>Go Base</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary me-1" @onclick='() => Go("grey")'>Go Grey</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success me-1" @onclick='() => Go("green")'>Go Green</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark me-1" @onclick='() => Go("purple")'>Go Purple</button>
</div>

@code {

    [Inject] private NavigationManager? NavManager { get; set; }
    
    private void Go(string colour)
        => this.NavManager?.NavigateTo($"/{colour}", true);
}
```

The Repo that contains the full solution is [here](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Medusa)

The site looks like this:

[image: Green Site]

Comment: This is brilliant work!  ...but the hot reload has stopped working.  any ideas on how to map that back through the routes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure.  I've had similar problems with hot reload on solutions.  Works then stops.  Haven't yet got to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: Me too.  When I have this problem, restarting VS fixes it for me.  However with the repo and its routing, this has broken hot reloading for an entirely different reason.

Comment: Any sample on multiple Blazor wasm but also with OIDC authentication? Not sure if each blazor SPA should be its own client Id or whether it should be managed on server side

Comment: I use two server blazor. i don't have `UseBlazorFrameworkFiles` in serverProjet2.  i need some nuget ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaMNQ.png

Comment: @Dev18 - please post this as a new question.  Reference this question as your starting point.

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis I post question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913304/merge-two-project-blazor-server