# Multitenancy with Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, multi-tenant

I have an application on Blazor WASM and it's already works. But now I need another project based on this one, where data and functionality in some places might be different, but all other information are same. At first time, I create dublicate project with it's own db and did my changes, but now I'm not sure, maybe in this case multitenancy can help me? In my case razor files also can be different for different tenants and this part I cannot handle. Any suggestion? If you can provide realy good information about multitenancy, I'll be very appreciate

Comment: "where data and functionality in some places might be different, but all other information are same." <-- This is not a helpful problem description, because it's completely vague.

Comment: Multi-tenancy is more about using a _single_ codebase and database (or at least a single database design) for multiple SaaS customers - it is not really concerned with project-management. It's also not something you can really bolt-on to an existing project because it's a very fundamental architectural aspect, it's something you have to write in stone from day 1.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  Do you want to have multiple SPAs hosted on the same same web site?  If so take a look at this recent answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71104254/create-a-multiple-webassembly-projects-in-a-single-solution/71116234#71116234

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.