# Multiple hosted ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly apps: An unhandled error has occurred. Reload 

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

In completing "[Multiple hosted ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1430836/multiple-hosted-asp-net-core-blazor-webassembly-ap)" successfully using the *port host*, I'm having trouble getting the *Route subpath hosting* working. I get this webpage and the browser debug console has this when navigating to https://localhost:5000/SecondApp/:

[image]

the Server Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// if serving pages or views from the server app
//app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/FirstApp",
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), first =>
    {
        first.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/FirstApp");
        first.UseStaticFiles();
        first.UseStaticFiles("/FirstApp");
        first.UseRouting();

        first.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/FirstApp/{*path:nonfile}",
                "FirstApp/index.html");
        });
    });

app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/SecondApp",
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), second =>
    {
        second.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/SecondApp");
        second.UseStaticFiles();
        second.UseStaticFiles("/SecondApp");
        second.UseRouting();

        second.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/SecondApp/{*path:nonfile}",
                "SecondApp/index.html");
        });
    });

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
// if serving pages or views from the server app
//app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

The Client.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <StaticWebAssetBasePath>FirstApp</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="7.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="7.0.13" PrivateAssets="all" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\RazorClassLibrary1\RazorClassLibrary1.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\BWAKohanyimApp.Shared.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The SecondClient.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <StaticWebAssetBasePath>SecondApp</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="7.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="7.0.13" PrivateAssets="all" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\RazorClassLibrary1\RazorClassLibrary1.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\BWAKohanyimApp.Shared.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The Server project's Properties/launchSettings.json:

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
      "windowsAuthentication": false,
      "anonymousAuthentication": true,
      "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:62789",
        "sslPort": 44326
      }
    },
    "profiles": {
      "http": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5154",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
      "https": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5000",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
      "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The project is set to serve pages or views from the server app and the server app launches correctly. How do I find what is causing the unhandled exception?

Comment: "How do I find what is causing the unhandled exception?" You can have a look at this   docs:[Handle errors in ASP.NET Core Blazor apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-8.0&preserve-view=true).  Is this answer you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71104254/create-a-multiple-webassembly-projects-in-a-single-solution/71116234#71116234